# Organizing MongoDB database containing different account types

Tags: mongodb, react-native, mongoose

I am working on a react-native app using nodejs and mongodb on the backend. In my app users are able to create multiple accounts and there are different account types (Business, Artist, Venue, etc.). For the most part, each account type has the same data and fields in the database. Things like name, location, website. But it is possible for each account type to have a couple pieces of data specific to that account. My question is, should I simply have one "Account" collection in the database that stores all accounts and has an "accountType" field to differentiate each account?

Initially I thought to do the opposite and store each account type in a separate collection, but I found it made the client code pretty messy as I found myself adding a bunch of if statements to determine things like what api endpoint to make requests to, what components to render, and what screens to navigate to, when in reality, it's really just a couple pieces of data that may change from one account type to another.

It seems like having just one "Accounts" collection with an "accountType" field will greatly simplify the code. But maybe there is something I am missing. If anyone has some insight as to which approach may be better for the situation, or some of the pros/cons of each approach, I'd really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer clearly depends on how the documents for different types of accounts differ. But, the idea of going with a single collection is fine, also take a look at the [Subset Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-subset-pattern), it's will give you a fine idea, of how to divide data into different collections, depending on their usage.